# Spray foam etched paint on aluminum window

Tags: repair, insulation, windows

I just had some new aluminum windows installed. When insulating around the window, a contractor had dripped a bit of spray foam onto part of the window assembly without noticing. A few hours later, it was noticed and removed using a rag, some Goof Off, and alcohol.

It looks like the foam etched the paint. The surface is smooth, so there's no residue from the foam remaining. The spot is visible under harsh lighting; I wanted to see if there were any viable repair options other than repainting the entire frame or replacing the frame.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps some kind of buffing/paint polishing

Comment: Use the 3foot rule.  If it is not easily evident when standing 3 feet away, under normal conditions, don't worry about it.  If you need special lighting to see it, you are being too critical.

Comment: I'm not convinced. You need a [solvent known to handle cured urethane](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/92016/how-to-clean-insulation-foam-residue-off-metal).

Comment: See also [How can I remove expanding foam residue?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/132503/remove-expansion-foam-residue)